# > Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, view

info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileJava

The Kotlin Gradle plugin was loaded multiple times in different subprojects, which is not supported and may break the build.
This might happen in subprojects that apply the Kotlin plugins with the Gradle 'plugins { ... }' DSL if they specify explicit versions, even if the versions are equal.
Please add the Kotlin plugin to the common parent project or the root project, then remove the versions in the subprojects.
If the parent project does not need the plugin, add 'apply false' to the plugin line.
See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl
The Kotlin plugin was loaded in the following projects: ':react-native-gesture-handler', ':react-native-screens'

> Task :react-native-clipboard_clipboard:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin

> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\Screen.kt: (77, 22): 'constructor GuardedRunnable(ReactContext!)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackFragment.kt: (62, 28): 'setter for targetElevation: Float' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackFragment.kt: (119, 28): 'setter for targetElevation: Float' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt: (85, 34): 'getter for systemWindowInsetTop: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt: (227, 37): 'setColorFilter(Int, PorterDuff.Mode): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenWindowTraits.kt: (64, 22): 'constructor GuardedRunnable(ReactContext!)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenWindowTraits.kt: (109, 22): 'constructor GuardedRunnable(ReactContext!)' is deprecated.
> Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenWindowTraits.kt: (118, 43): 'replaceSystemWindowInsets(Int, Int, Int, Int): WindowInsetsCompat' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenWindowTraits.kt: (119, 47): 'getter for systemWindowInsetLeft: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenWindowTraits.kt: (121, 47): 'getter for systemWindowInsetRight: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenWindowTraits.kt: (122, 47): 'getter for systemWindowInsetBottom: Int' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\SearchBarView.kt: (141, 43): Parameter 'flag' is never used
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderAttachedEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderAttachedEvent.kt: (7, 42): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderAttachedEvent.kt: (17, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderAttachedEvent.kt: (18, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderBackButtonClickedEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderBackButtonClickedEvent.kt: (7, 51): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderBackButtonClickedEvent.kt: (17, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated
> in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderBackButtonClickedEvent.kt: (18, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderDetachedEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderDetachedEvent.kt: (7, 42): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderDetachedEvent.kt: (17, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\HeaderDetachedEvent.kt: (18, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenAppearEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenAppearEvent.kt: (7, 40): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is
> deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenAppearEvent.kt: (13, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenAppearEvent.kt: (14, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenDisappearEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenDisappearEvent.kt: (7, 43): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)'
> is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenDisappearEvent.kt: (13, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenDisappearEvent.kt: (14, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is
> deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenDismissedEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenDismissedEvent.kt: (7, 43): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)'
> is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenDismissedEvent.kt: (13, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenDismissedEvent.kt: (17, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is
> deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenTransitionProgressEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated
> in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenTransitionProgressEvent.kt: (13, 5): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenTransitionProgressEvent.kt: (22, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenTransitionProgressEvent.kt: (27, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?):
> Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenWillAppearEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenWillAppearEvent.kt: (7, 44): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenWillAppearEvent.kt: (13, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Javaw: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenWillAppearEvent.kt: (14, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenWillDisappearEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenWillDisappearEvent.kt: (7, 47): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenWillDisappearEvent.kt: (13, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\ScreenWillDisappearEvent.kt: (14, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarBlurEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarBlurEvent.kt: (7, 41): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarBlurEvent.kt: (17, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarBlurEvent.kt: (18, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarChangeTextEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarChangeTextEvent.kt: (10, 5): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarChangeTextEvent.kt: (20, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarChangeTextEvent.kt: (23, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarCloseEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarCloseEvent.kt: (7, 42): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarCloseEvent.kt: (17, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarCloseEvent.kt: (18, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarFocusEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarFocusEvent.kt: (7, 42): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarFocusEvent.kt: (17, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarFocusEvent.kt: (18, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarOpenEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarOpenEvent.kt: (7, 41): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarOpenEvent.kt: (17, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarOpenEvent.kt: (18, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarSearchButtonPressEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarSearchButtonPressEvent.kt: (7, 81): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarSearchButtonPressEvent.kt: (17, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\SearchBarSearchButtonPressEvent.kt: (20, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?): Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\StackFinishTransitioningEvent.kt: (5, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated
> in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\StackFinishTransitioningEvent.kt: (7, 52): 'constructor Event<T : Event<(raw) Event<*>>!>(Int)' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\StackFinishTransitioningEvent.kt: (13, 44): 'RCTEventEmitter' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\events\StackFinishTransitioningEvent.kt: (14, 25): 'receiveEvent(Int, String!, WritableMap?):
> Unit' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\paper\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\FabricEnabledViewGroup.kt: (7, 42): Parameter 'width' is never used
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\paper\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\FabricEnabledViewGroup.kt: (7, 54): Parameter 'height' is never used

> Task :react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

> Task :react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin
> w: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\android\src\main\java\com\th3rdwave\safeareacontext\SafeAreaView.kt: (58, 23): 'getter for uiImplementation: UIImplementation!' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
> w: Detected multiple Kotlin daemon sessions at build\kotlin\sessions

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
78 actionable tasks: 77 executed, 1 up-to-date
Note: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\codegen\generator\SchemaJsonParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules@react-native-clipboard\clipboard\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\clipboard\ClipboardModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.kt: (247, 92): Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 47s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Note: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\java\com\facebook\react\codegen\generator\SchemaJsonParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules@react-native-clipboard\clipboard\android\src\main\java\com\reactnativecommunity\clipboard\ClipboardModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
e: C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\react-native-gesture-handler\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\gesturehandler\react\RNGestureHandlerButtonViewManager.kt: (247, 92): Unresolved reference: TIRAMISU

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8m 47s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\Major\VirtualWardrobe\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Clean Gradle Cache: Sometimes, Gradle caches can cause issues. Try cleaning the Gradle cache by running the following commands:

For Windows:

```
gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

For macOS/Linux:

```
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

If not ok with above solution,

Update Libraries: Make sure all your React Native libraries are up-to-date. Run the following commands to update the libraries: with `npm update` or `yarn upgrade`